# whatsapp url scheme text for individual users/groups

Tags: ios, whatsapp

I have an iOS app and I am using URL Scheme of Whatsapp for sending text to user's whatsapp friends.

I am wondering if there is a way that the string of text i send can be changed by the fact that the user sends the text to an individual or a group.

Just to make myself clear, is there a way for me to send different string of text when a user chooses to send that string to a group? I want to change the singular statements to plural if user sends message to a group.

Comment: No currently there is not any way of doing this, as you can not control another app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although of course I have found that out months ago :) Thank you anyway